# Uniform Way to Guide caching using Http Header fields

Tags: css, http, caching

I am currently implementing and reconsidering cache control using headers.

Beside dynamic resources (no-cache) the following can be seen in the wilde:

- Static pictures never meant to change -> Expires in a year
- JS / CSS not often changing -> A year
- JS / CSS subject to change -> A week to 72hours
- JS / CSS often changes -> up to 15minutes

Also some use versionized / randomized parts in the resource names like main_v2.3.1.js.

Some use max-age, and some use last modified.

Barely I saw eTag usage.

But from my understanding eTag usage might be the most flexible. The date format must be correct or the cache will switch to revalidate where the server takes responsibility to value If-Modified-Since values and send a Not Changed response.

Also I saw one version using 'v0' as an eTag.

My consideration is that if I stick to single resource locations without adding versionized names (appending randoms or versions) I have to rely on eTags and LastModified and Max-Ages.

One can clearly see that old CMS systems use the traditional date based approach where as others use the eTag in combination with max-age.

So now the question is do I have to utilize both today or can I soley rely on max-age and eTag to control the validation process and for max-age control the revalidation frequency? I would like to avoid time format related fun using Expires and Last Modified.

Comment: I think your answer should be at your webservers cache control, and not in HTTP headers

Comment: I have an in-house web-server embedded into jetty but being totally in control of headers and alike. So there is no cache control server side setting I have to or better can tweak. So I look for a reliable cross browser cross platform cross device solution.